# Calender.getTime() always returns similar values after Calender.set(Calender.TIME_ARG, time)

Tags: java, android

I have written function to help me return bounds to a week of a selected value of week and year but I keep getting the same bound for each variable of week and Year i pass to the method.

```
public static String getWeekBounds(int year, int week){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    int firstDayOfWeek = c.getFirstDayOfWeek();
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, firstDayOfWeek);
    String result = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy",Locale.getDefault()).format(c.getTime()) + "~";
    int lastDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek+6;
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, lastDayOfWeek);
    result += new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy",Locale.getDefault()).format(c.getTime());

    return result;
}
```

I want the function to return the right value of week bounds.

Comment: If you want to increase the date by 7 days use `c.add` not `firstDayOfWeek+6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of calling c.getTime() after setting time to comfirm values that have been set is what solved the problem for me.

```
public static String getWeekBounds(int year, int week){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.getTime(); //line added that removed the glitch
    int firstDayOfWeek = c.getFirstDayOfWeek();
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, firstDayOfWeek);
    String result = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy",Locale.getDefault()).format(c.getTime()) + "~";
    int lastDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek+6;
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, lastDayOfWeek);
    result += new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy",Locale.getDefault()).format(c.getTime());

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way for the first day of week:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);          
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```

and for the last day of week

```
c.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week+1);
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -1);
System.out.println(sdf.format(c.getTime()));
```